# Github page is not showing and keeps loading

Tags: html, github, openlayers, web-hosting

I have published a Github Pages under this link: https://rochanofa.github.io/unesco-seasia/. It is a web-map application based on OpenLayers library. 
However, the content of the page is not showing and the page keeps loading forever.
When I open the index.html file in my local directory the content is displayed on my web browser. Here is the screenshot of the webpage when I load from my local computer.

[image]

What could I possibly do wrong?
The link to the repository includes the javascript code: https://github.com/rochanofa/unesco-seasia

Comment: It's loaded for me and title says _UNESCO Heritage Site - South East Asia_

Comment: @Shashank Yes the title appears but the content of the page (HTML body) doesn't. I will update my question with the screenshot of how the webpage should look like

Answer (score 0):

### Looping redirects

I can't tell where it's coming from in the code, but if you load the page with the network tab open, and check "Preserve log" it appears that the root `/` redirects to `unesco-seasia/` and that page redirects back to `/`. Normally browsers catch this, but it's using HTTP 307, instead of 302 or 301.

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this? I am not familiar with web hosting